# I am going to create simple logger using C# so what are the design patterns I can use to create this as best practice?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Usually loggers are used to log given message (error, warnings or information) to a log file (simple text file or xml)

Comment: The best practice here is "do not create yet another logger, please".

Comment: [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a good choice

Comment: It's a fair question. There can be many reasons for rolling your own, one of them "to experiment and learn about design patterns".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the obvious choces are Strategy (one logger that can be configured to use different output options) and Composite (multiplex output over several output outions).

So something like this (in Java):

```
public class Logger {

  public interface LogOutput {
    void out(final String s);
  }

  // Composite - use to send logging to several destinations
  public LogOutput makeComposite(final LogOutput... loggers) {
    return new LogOutput() {
      void out(final String s) {
        for (final LogOutput l : loggers) {
          l.out(s);
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private static currentLogger = new LogOutput() {
    void out(final String s) {
       // Do nothing as default - no strategy set
    }
  }

  public static log(final String s) {
    currentLogger.out(s);
  }


  // Strategy: Set a new strategy for output
  public static setLogger(final LogOutput l) {
    currentLogger = l;
  }

}
```